# Foxit Reader prevents windows restart

Tags: windows, reboot, foxit-reader

Simply put, if I have the Foxit reader (2023.3) open and try to restart Windows 11, for windows updates or whatever, Foxit blocks it. This obviously creates issues, not the least of which is annoyance at this behaviour, but also interferes with automated restarts.

Yes, I can manually close Foxit previously, but normally *only* programs that have unsaved documents open will do that, e.g. word. I don't have foxit editor and usually I don't have any forms open that'd justify that. In any case, foxit doesn't show you any dialog box "do you want to save this document", it just silently sulks there, preventing the reboot.

Is there a way to stop Foxit from behaving like this?

Comment: Not reproducible here. Which build of Windows 11 do you have, and which version/build of FoxIt?

Comment: Is Foxit holding open a dialog ?

Comment: Or use another reader, such as quick Sumatra PDF, https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader, or versatile PDF-XChange Editor, https://pdf-xchange.eu/pdf-xchange-editor/.